# How can i get HTML input to PHP without submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically, i got a form/submit form, but it doesn't post to my site since it's a paypal payment gateway but i need a value from one of the text input fields how can i accomplish this without post/get? I heard you can do it with JS, i tried some JS code but it didn't really work

PAYPAL_URL is a defined variable in config_payment.php that's just a PayPal URL.

My code:

```
<form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="inform">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="fakeform">
                <table class="aligntop">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Username</th>
                            <td><input class="payment-field" id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="80"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">User ID</th>
                            <td><input class="payment-field" id="userid" type="text" name="userid" value="<?php echo $pun_user['id'] ?>" maxlength="80"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Email</th>
                            <td><input class="payment-field" id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" maxlength="80"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Plan</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="validity" onchange="getSubsPrice(this);" class="payment-field">
                                    <option value="1" selected="selected">1 Month - $20</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var getuserid=document.getElementById('userid').value;
                               
                        </script>
                        <?php
                            $phpVar = "<script>document.writeln(getuserid);</script>";
                            ?>
                        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_ID; ?>">
                        <!-- Specify a subscriptions button. -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
                        <!-- Specify details about the subscription that buyers will purchase -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $itemName; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="paypalAmt" value="<?php echo $itemPrice; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="p3" id="paypalValid" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
                        <!-- Custom variable user ID -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $phpVar; ?>">
                        <!-- Specify urls -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_RETURN_URL; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_NOTIFY_URL; ?>">
            </div>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="centered">
                <input class="buy-btn" type="submit" value="Buy Subscription">
            </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see i tried some JS and PHP merging, but it's still 0 when i retrieve it and post it

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var getuserid=document.getElementById('userid').value;
                               
                        </script>
                        <?php
                            $phpVar = "<script>document.writeln(getuserid);</script>";
                            ?>
```

Please if anyone can point out what im doing wrong, im eternally greatful thanks.

Comment: PHP and JavaScript do not run together. PHP runs on server. JavaScript in the browser. Learn about the page life cycle.

Comment: Then how am i supposed to get the HTML input, if i can't get the POST data since it's sending it to paypal's URL? Any other solutions?

Comment: It is unclear... it is the value in the input field. Why are you not just using that input field. `id="userid" type="text" name="userid"` just name it custom.....

Comment: Or onchange of the filed, set the hidden filed value with JavaScript.

Comment: You mean the echo yes, but basically so i want it so you can enter another ID, basically so i can enter my friends ID and purchase for him, but he gets the perks (his userid) so that's why i need the value entered in the input so i can use it in here: <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $phpVar; ?>">

Comment: @epascarello Renamed userid field to custom field, and removed the other one, worked like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs before any JavaScript executes so what you want to do ins not possible.

Seems like you want the value to update another field if it changes.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $pun_user['id'] ?>">
```

and add a simple script

```
document.querySelector("#userid").addEventListener("change", function(){
  document.querySelector('[name="custom"]').value = this.value;
});
```

---

Simpler solution, get rid of the hidden element and rename the userid field.

```
<td><input class="payment-field" id="userid" type="text" name="custom" value="<?php echo $pun_user['id'] ?>" maxlength="80"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach in my opinion would be to use your server as the middle man between the '***User***' and '***PayPal***'.

That is, instead of the ***User*** submitting directly to ***PayPal***, you could have the ***User*** submit to your server instead. With that, you have access to that input field you really wanted and you're able to also validate that form.

Finally, your server would resubmit the *same* request to ***PayPal***, receive the response, perform other necessary operations, and send it back to the ***User***.

i.e

1. User -- *PayPal request* ---> Server
2. Server -- *validate form, get that input field you want, resubmit request* ---> PayPal
3. PayPal -- *PayPal response*---> Server
4. Server -- *perform some operations i.e. saving to database, send PayPal response*---> User